# How to validate nested array of multiple types using class-validator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I use nestjs with class-validator, and I have the following case:

- Two classes with same field name that has different types:

```
class A {
  @IsDefined()
  field: number;
}

class B {
  @IsDefined()
  field: string;
}
```

- Third class that has array of elements from types A or B, my problem is how to validate each array member against its own class:

```
class C {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(I_DON'T_KNOW_WHAT_TO_DO_HERE)
  array: (A | B)[];
}
```

How can I validate the array?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a descriminative field, to allow the class-transformer to identify the type to cast and use in the validation. The same can be done with nested objects.

In the example below, if the property `"version"` is equal to "v1", then the `field` should be a `number`, in the other hand, if the property `version` is equal to "v2" the property `field` should be a `string`.

In the `discriminator` property you should set a field to be used to identify the different polymorphic forms of the nested objects. The `subTypes.[].value` is the class to be used in validation and `subTypes.[].name` is the value that the `discriminator` field should have to assume the class added in the `subTypes.[].name` field.

```js
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsDefined, IsEnum, IsNumber, IsString, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

enum VersionEnum {
  VERSION_1 = 'v1',
  VERSION_2 = 'v2',
}

class Discriminator {
  @IsEnum(VersionEnum)
  version: VersionEnum;
}

class A extends Discriminator {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNumber()
  field: number;
}

class B extends Discriminator {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  field: string;
}

export class C {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => Discriminator, {
    discriminator: {
      property: 'version',
      subTypes: [
        { value: A, name: VersionEnum.VERSION_1 },
        { value: B, name: VersionEnum.VERSION_2 },
      ],
    },
    keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
  })
  array: (A | B)[];
}
```

Now your controller should look like this:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Post()
  public example(
    @Body(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
    body: C,
  ) {
    return body;
  }
}
```

And you can do your requests:

```bash
curl --location 'localhost:3000/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "array": [
    {
      "version": "v1",
      "field": 1
    },
    {
      "version": "v2",
      "field": "2"
    }
  ]
}'
```

If you change the second element of the nested array to be a number with the `version` property as "v2", then you will see an error:

```
{
  "version": "v2",
- "field": "2"
+ "field": 2
}
```

```bash
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "array.1.field must be a string"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

References:
https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#providing-more-than-one-type-option

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! 
Isn't the discriminator solution a little bit messy? The need for changing the original object just for the validator does not seem much of a clean code

Comment: You can also look for one property which exists in one object and not in the other and verify if the value is undefined or is another value. I think that the options of "@Type" should be improved and have some open issues to do it.

Comment: Agreed about the last sentence. I checked the link you gave in the answer and it really seems like the discriminator is the only appropriate solution. Thanks!